# Recycleview привязка к низу экрана

Tags: android, recyclerview

Приветсвую. 
Перерыл доступную доку, так и не нашел как реализовать заполнение recycleview по принципу месенджеров. Т.е. первый элемент внизу, и далее по мере добавления элементов список сдвигается.
Прошу, нижайше, выпрямить руки и указать путь к просвещению.

Answer (score 2):

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true); // нужный параметр
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Спасибо, пинок в верном направлении. Только заполнение теперь идет сверху. И почемуто 
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
не помогает. А вместо ожидаемого заполнения снизу со сдвигом, фактически, инверсировало действие setReverseLayout...

Comment: Оказывается для моей задачи нужет был соло
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)
без использвания  
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true
Тем не менее, спасибо.